# React Native FlatList - Variable columns

Tags: flexbox, react-native, react-native-ios

I am developing a infinitely scrolling list of products which contain different types of products. A product can be featured or not featured. When a product is featured, we have a product card design that takes up the full width of the phone, otherwise the design calls for a 2 column row

The data looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "type": "featured-product",
    "name": "Product",
    "description: "yadda yadda"
  },
  {
    "type": "product",
    "name": "Another Product",
    "description: "yadda yadda"
  },
  {
    "type": "product",
    "name": "And Another Product",
    "description: "yadda yadda"
  },
  {
    "type": "product",
    "name": "One more Product",
    "description: "yadda yadda"
  }
  {
    "type": "product",
    "name": "Yet another",
    "description: "yadda yadda"
  },
  {
    "type": "featured-product",
    "name": "This one's Featured though",
    "description: "yadda yadda"
  }
]
```

For example, the list would look something like this:

```
--------------
|            |
|  Featured  |
|            |
--------------
|     ||     |
| Not || Not |
|     ||     |
--------------
|     ||     |
| Not || Not |
|     ||     |
--------------
|            |
|  Featured  |
|            |
--------------
|     ||     |
| Not || Not |
|     ||     |
--------------
|     ||     |
| Not || Not |
|     ||     |
--------------
```

However, with the [`FlatList`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) component, I'm not having luck achieving this design's layout.

- Adding styles to each respective item `flex: 1` on full width and `flex: 0.5` on double column doesn't allow for wrapping columns and always displays a single column row
- Setting the `numColumns` prop to 2 displays the products somewhat properly, but causes issues with the full width featured item.
- Thought about chunking the items by 2 and having them represent one item, but that's proving to require much more overhead while using Flow

I was venturing down the path of using a FlatList for the performance benefits, but I'm starting to think it might not be suited for the layout that I require.

Has anyone solved this before?

Comment: Can you post the your `renderer` code for the FlatList data?

Comment: If you provide us with the rendered markup, we might be able to suggest a solution.

Comment: [react-native-super-grid](https://github.com/saleel/react-native-super-grid) might be useful to you, along with @bennygenel's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know FlatList renders each item in data on its own row. The desired behavior of what you ask is not possible unless you manipulate the native side to create a desired behavior component.

I think your best/easiest way to go is third option. What you can do I think somehow manipulate your data being rendered and group every other "not featured" items in two and get them rendered together.

**For Example**

```
renderItem({item}) {
  if (item.notFeatured === true) return <NotFeaturedRow data={item.items} />
  else return <FeaturedRow data={item} />
}

const data = [
  {
    "type": "featured-product",
    "name": "Product",
    "description: "yadda yadda"
  },
  {
    notFeatured: true, 
    items: [
      {
        "type": "product",
        "name": "Another Product",
        "description: "yadda yadda"
     },
     {
        "type": "product",
        "name": "And Another Product",
        "description: "yadda yadda"
      }    
    ]
  },
  {
    notFeatured: true, 
    items: [
      {
        "type": "product",
        "name": "Another Product",
        "description: "yadda yadda"
     },
     {
        "type": "product",
        "name": "And Another Product",
        "description: "yadda yadda"
      }    
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "featured-product",
    "name": "This one's Featured though",
    "description: "yadda yadda"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I ended up going with the third option. However I used a different data structure, it still worked perfectly fine.

Comment: @Seth mine was just an example to show whats in my mind. I'm glad that it worked for you. Your welcome

Answer (score 1):

Just use RecyclerListView instead. It is faster than FlatList and battle tested at Flipkart. It supports staggered layouts.

Link: https://github.com/Flipkart/ReactEssentials

You can read more about it here: https://medium.com/@naqvitalha/recyclerlistview-high-performance-listview-for-react-native-and-web-e368d6f0d7ef

Comment: Does it work with expo or im going to have to eject the app?