# ReactNative Flat list Odd cards full width

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have 12 card view on homescreen

im using Flat list to render the 12 cards

I have 2 columns set so 2 cards in the view

i would like to tweak it so after every 2 cards 1 card be full width then the next 2 cards next to each other and the third is full width and so on

here is my code

```
        <FlatList

    data={ this.state.GridListItems }
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}

    renderItem={ ({item, index}) =>

      <TouchableOpacity style={{width: (index + 1) % 3 === 0 ? '108%' : '54%', height: '110%', justifyContent:'center',        overflow: "hidden",
      flex:1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      margin: 5,
      backgroundColor: '#231F20',
      borderRadius: 5,
      shadowColor: '#000',
      shadowOffset: { width: 5, height: 5 },
      shadowOpacity: 0.8,
      shadowRadius: 5,
      elevation: 6,
      padding: 5,}}
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ProfileScreen', { height: "6'2", category: item.key })}>
      <ImageBackground
        source={{ uri: item.img }}
        style={{width: '108%', height: '110%', justifyContent:'center'}} >
        <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>          
          <Text style={styles.GridViewTextLayout}  > {item.key} </Text>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>

      </TouchableOpacity>
  }
  numColumns={2}
  initialNumToRender={6}
```

/>

i want it to render 2 cards (each card 50% of screen) and every third card (100% of the screen) for the 12 element

Comment: renderItem takes two arguments (item, index), you can check the index if % 2 = 0, apply your odd style

Comment: what should i put in index ?  i don't have index

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native FlatList with alternate rows having different number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49666330/react-native-flatlist-with-alternate-rows-having-different-number-of-columns)

Comment: @devas `index % 2 === 0` wouldn't work well for every third card. you should add 1 to the index, like `(index + 1) % 3 === 0`.

Comment: Hmm, Can you explain to me why to do that? @kenmistry

Comment: @devas, your proposed `index` argument works well with odd numbered items, but not for every third item. for example, in this array `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`, `index % 2 === 0` gets you `0, 2, 4, 6, 8` while `(index + 1) % 3 === 0` gets you `2, 5, 8`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this. so, on every third card, it should display the full width.

```
const styles = {
  GridViewContainer: {
    justifyContent:'center',
    overflow: "hidden",
    flex:1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    margin: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#231F20',
    borderRadius: 5,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 5, height: 5 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 5,
    elevation: 6,
    padding: 5,
  }
}

<FlatList
  data={this.state.GridListItems}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
  renderItem={({item, index}) =>
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.GridViewContainer}
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ProfileScreen', { height: "6'2", category: item.key })}
    >
      <ImageBackground
        source={{ uri: item.img }}
        style={{
          width: (index + 1) % 3 === 0 ? '216%' : '108%',
          height: '110%',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
          }}
        >          
          <Text style={styles.GridViewTextLayout}> {item.key} </Text>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  }
  numColumns={2}
  initialNumToRender={6}
/>
```

**edited to reflect the styling for `GridViewContainer`**

Comment: it worked but it resized the background image instead of resizing the touchableOpacity

Comment: https://scontent-hbe1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/67371428_870019093353974_2680857820965896192_n.jpg?_nc_cat=102&_nc_oc=AQkeWlz11tqQN5oBzHWEQ_SBK0c0w_781LpBpjYt4FUnAS2biq0yGmLepsGujMdDUJQ&_nc_ht=scontent-hbe1-1.xx&oh=e84d184f1c14c733c0e166b2775d2182&oe=5DB21AC5

Comment: well, the styling for `GridViewContainer` is not included in the question. you can proceed to apply the same styling on it.

Comment: i updated the code to add the styles i tried it but now i get only 2 cards and rest of screen is empty

Comment: @mohamedadel, can you remove the specified height and width for `<TouchableOpacity />` and let it conform to the height and width specified in the `<ImageBackground />`? speaking from experience, `<Image />` and `<ImageBackground />` work best when both height and width are specified.

Comment: sorry how can i do that ? im new

Comment: i've updated my answer and removed the height and width for `<TouchableOpacity />` and relocated it under `<ImageBackground />`. can you apply my code and see if it is working on your end?

Comment: here is what i got https://scontent-hbe1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/67398350_798866480510769_5756919046243090432_n.jpg?_nc_cat=105&_nc_oc=AQmBS4hqioDc_K4xEYUQBBuiOjvG0QGmthxYMvjX-rt7k3JsEGl6KeOK_Iborw1g-CY&_nc_ht=scontent-hbe1-1.xx&oh=9949dc79ffc2a02cea322dcc4bcc4270&oe=5DE0054D

Comment: @mohamedadel, my bad. it should be `216%` instead of `54%`. see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks very much copying and pasting the code now i get 
https://scontent-hbe1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/67607714_2407009609556383_5388533872994549760_n.jpg?_nc_cat=109&_nc_oc=AQlhH0pyBUwfi91QsiaDT4hv5R76uEwHR9eDbibQjlHnV1_7Z4FoNPydIaR4YeVvuVQ&_nc_ht=scontent-hbe1-1.xx&oh=b0d66c11402f5f05d0a6ca40118f9adf&oe=5DAB23A3
i think we are getting close ?

Comment: Sorry, but can you draw what's the final result should be because I don't understand what's you mean? @mohamedadel

Comment: this should be the final result https://i.ibb.co/MMtCKjy/QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ.png
im really happy with your help guys

Comment: @mohamedadel so close. haha. can you revert the styling for `<TouchableOpacity />` to `GridViewContainer`? i believe that's what it is causing the empty list. and, it isn't clear to me what is dictating the width of each item. can you inspect the item elements and find out where it is getting its width values from?

Comment: i don't quite understand what you mean :D 
here is the current repo for the project
https://github.com/Ov3rControl/Weddi
so to have a better understanding thanks

Comment: @mohamedadel, it seems like it isn't possible to do it with `FlatList`. you may have to separate the list into two rows, even and odd, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46534449/react-native-flatlist-variable-columns)